# Query function with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet and I want to search for two criteria in two different columns. When i entre my equations it returns no data except the column headings.

=QUERY(MukuluFarmsMasterData,"select A,B,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V where B = 'SERVICING' and F = 1")

So I want the table to return all the information that satisfy both conditions. So in column B I want everything that is Servicing and From column F = 1. I would also like to sort the date in Descending order.

This is a screenshot of the spreadsheet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVY7u.png)

Comment: without access to the sheet it's hard to tell where the problem is. Would you mind sharing a copy of it with edit rights?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.